# Using PDF.js , Is it possible to get link URLs' and its relative coordinates ( positions of X_Y || top_left ) from a pdf file?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

Does anyone know any websites with a complete example of how to get coordinates of URL links put in pdf file using PDF.js?

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

---

**I need data below.**

- Link URLs of each links.
- XY coordinates of each links.
- The Size of the page.
- ID or name of the page.

I want to put(hover) those links on jpg images which are extracted using pdf.js.
To calculate where to put the links , I need its coordinates.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm only extracting the links, you can get the extra info from the `pdfDocument` if you need it.

I'm using [linkify](https://github.com/Hypercontext/linkifyjs) to help with the links string parse.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('fileSelector');
const readFile = ()=> {
  const file = input.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', readPDF);
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};
const readPDF = async (event)=> {
  const typedarray = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
  const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(typedarray);
  const pdfDocument = await loadingTask.promise;
  for (let pageNum=1; pageNum<=pdfDocument.numPages; pageNum++) {
    readPage(pdfDocument, pageNum);
  }
};
const readPage = async (pdfDocument, pageNum)=> {
  const page = await pdfDocument.getPage(pageNum);
  const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
  for (let item of textContent.items) {
    const links = linkify.find(item.str);
    for (let link of links) appendLink(link);
  }
};
const appendLink = (link)=> {
  const list = document.getElementById('list');
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = link.href;
  a.textContent = link.value;
  list.appendChild(a);
}
input.addEventListener('change', readFile);
```

```css
a { display: block }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/linkifyjs@3.0.3/dist/linkify.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" accept=".pdf" id="fileSelector">
<div id="list"></div>
```